# MPFR giving NaN answer when all inputs are correct

Tags: c, gmp, mpfr

I have a small program written in C that uses MFPR and GMP to compute Pi to lots of decimal places using the [Chudnovsky algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chudnovsky_algorithm).

Here is the code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gmp.h>
#include <mpfr.h>

int main() {
  mpfr_t m, m1, m2;
  mpfr_t l;
  mpz_t x, x1;
  mpfr_t series, s1;
  mpfr_t c;

  mpfr_set_default_prec(1000000);
  mpfr_init_set_ui(m, 1, MPFR_RNDN);
  mpfr_init(m1);
  mpfr_init(m2);

  mpfr_init_set_ui(l, 13591409, MPFR_RNDN);

  mpz_init_set_ui(x, 1);
  mpz_init_set_str(x1, "-262537412640768000", 10);

  mpfr_init_set_ui(series, 0, MPFR_RNDN);
  mpfr_init(s1);

  mpfr_init_set_ui(c, 10005, MPFR_RNDN);
  mpfr_sqrt(c, c, MPFR_RNDN);
  mpfr_mul_ui(c, c, 426880, MPFR_RNDN);

  for(unsigned int k = 0; k < 1000; ++k) {
    // series += (m * l) / x
    mpfr_mul(s1, m, l, MPFR_RNDN);
    mpfr_printf("m * l: %Rf\n", s1);
    mpfr_div_z(s1, s1, x, MPFR_RNDN);
    mpfr_printf("(m * l) / x: %Rf\n", s1);

    mpfr_add(series, series, s1, MPFR_RNDN);
    mpfr_printf("series: %Rf\n", series);

    // (12k + 2)(12k + 6)(12k + 10)
    mpfr_set_ui(m1, 12, MPFR_RNDN);
    mpfr_mul_ui(m1, m1, k, MPFR_RNDN);
    mpfr_add_ui(m1, m1, 2, MPFR_RNDN);

    mpfr_set_ui(m2, 12, MPFR_RNDN);
    mpfr_mul_ui(m2, m2, k, MPFR_RNDN);
    mpfr_add_ui(m2, m2, 6, MPFR_RNDN);
    mpfr_mul(m1, m1, m2, MPFR_RNDN);

    mpfr_set_ui(m2, 12, MPFR_RNDN);
    mpfr_mul_ui(m2, m2, k, MPFR_RNDN);
    mpfr_add_ui(m2, m2, 10, MPFR_RNDN);
    mpfr_mul(m1, m1, m2, MPFR_RNDN);

    // (k + 1)^3
    mpfr_set_ui(m2, k + 1, MPFR_RNDN);
    mpfr_pow_ui(m2, m2, 3, MPFR_RNDN);

    // (12k + 2)(12k + 6)(12k + 10)
    // ----------------------------
    //          (k + 1)^3
    mpfr_div(m, m1, m2, MPFR_RNDN);

    // l += 545140134
    mpfr_add_ui(l, l, 545140134, MPFR_RNDN);

    // x *= -262537412640768000
    mpz_mul(x, x, x1);
  }

  mpfr_printf("m: %Rf\nl: %Rf\n", m, l);
  gmp_printf("x: %Zd\n", x);
  mpfr_printf("series: %Rf\n", series);

  mpfr_div(c, c, series, MPFR_RNDN);
  mpfr_printf("pi: %Rf\n", c);

  mpfr_clear(m);
  mpfr_clear(m1);
  mpfr_clear(m2);

  mpfr_clear(l);

  mpz_clear(x);
  mpz_clear(x1);

  mpfr_clear(series);
  mpfr_clear(s1);

  mpfr_clear(c);

  mpfr_free_cache();
  return 0;
}
```

When I run the program it prints values for `m, l, x and series` however it always prints out `nan` for `s1`.

I have tried placing print statements all over the code to figure out where it goes wrong and the problem seems to be in the call to `mpfr_div_z(s1, s1, x, MPFR_RNDN)` as it keeps alternating between having the value `-0` and `0`. I have googled for potential solutions but found nothing

Comment: I can't reproduce this.  When I run your code, it runs to completion and no nan's are output.  This is libmpfr 4.0.2-1 and libgmp 2:6.1.2+dfsg-4 on Ubuntu 19.10 x86-64.

Comment: That's strange I'm on Ubuntu 19.10 x86-64 too

Comment: Compiler options?

Comment: Here is the compiler command line (run from a Makefile) `gcc -o main main.c -Wall -Wextra -lmpfr -lgmp`

Comment: Nope, still can't reproduce.

Comment: @NateEldredge whilst it was outputting did you notice it alternating between this output `(m * l) / x: 0.000000` and `(m * l) / x: -0.000000` because that's the behaviour that is causing a major problem as you'll see the value of `series` never changes explaining why we get some kind of correct answer however that it not the complete result of the entire computation

Comment: The value of `(m * l) / x` is changing, and it isn't zero; it's just that it's always very small, and you're printing in fixed point, so you never see what's happening past the 6th decimal place.  Try changing `%Rf` in that line to something like `%.10Re` and you'll see it.

Comment: So wait, on which line exactly were you seeing `nan`?  And at which iteration of the loop?

Comment: In fact, can you just post the entire output you get from the program when you run it (e.g. in a gist or pastebin somewhere)?

Comment: Whilst yes it's value very quickly approaches 0 the value of `(m * l) / x` does not reflect the values it should as proven by this python script `https://pastebin.com/fi42tRFt`. The python script is simply an implementation of the same algorithm in Python

Comment: I don't get any NaN either. And it is normal that `(m * l) / x` becomes very small since the series converges quickly.